# Serie en Java: 2,-3,-5,-7,4,-5,-7,-9

Tags: java

tengo esta serie como tarea:
2, - 3, - 5, -7 , 4 , 6, -9, - 11, - 13,
            8, 10, 12, -15, -17, -19, 14, . . . .
llevo rato intentando encontrar la solución pero no he logrado nada. 
Espero que me digan en qué estoy mal
Mi codigo hasta el momento:

```
  package com.mycompany.java;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Java1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         /*Construya un programa en JAVA y RUBY. Que calcule e
            imprima la siguiente serie para los N primeros
            términos
       2, ─ 3, ─ 5, ─ 7 , 4 , 6, ─ 9, ─ 11, ─ 13,
        8, 10, 12, -15, -17, -19, 14, . . . .   */

       int n, i, j;
       int num=0;
       int num1=0;
       n = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite el valor de N: "));

       for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
            if(i%2==0){//si es par

                for(int a=0;a<=i;a++){  
                num1 = i
                System.out.print(num1+",");
                }


                for(j=1;j<=3;j++){
                num = (i*2-1) * -1;
                System.out.print(num+",");
                }

}

}
}



}
```

Comment: Ya sabes como calcular la serie?

Comment: Sí, creo que la lógica de la serie la entendí, el problema es que no logro hacer que respete los valores de N y tampoco logro hacer la serie correctamente

Comment: La lógica de la serie dice que: muestras n pares positivos, luego 3 enteros negativos, luego los siguientes n+1 pares positivos, luego los siguientes 3 enteros negativos, luego los siguientes n+2 pares positivos, luego los siguientes 3 enteros negativos,... la serie de los positivos y los negativos la tienes que llevar en dos conteos separados para saber cuál par o impar sigue.

Answer (score 0):

Te agrego una solución:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        // la cantidad de números de la secuencia a generar
        int cantidadAGenerar = 10;
        // el inicio de los número pares
        int inicioPares = 2;
        //el inicio de los números impares
        int inicioImpares = -3;

        // arreglo para almacenar los números generados
        int[] numerosGenerados = new int[cantidadAGenerar];

        // contador para dar seguimiento a los números generados
        int contador = 0;
        // en cada iteración se imprimen n + 1 números pares
        // esta variable permite llevar la secuencia
        int cantidadPares = 1;

        // iterar mientras no se hayan generado todos lo números
        while(contador < cantidadAGenerar){

            // imprimir secuencia de números pares, en la primera iteración imprime solo un número
            // en la segunda dos números ...
            for (int i = 0; i < cantidadPares; i++) {
                 // si ya se generaron todos lo números terminar
                if(contador == cantidadAGenerar) break;
                // guardar el número generado en el arreglo
                numerosGenerados[contador++] = inicioPares;
                // incrementar el siguiente número par
                inicioPares +=2;
            }

            // en la siguiente iteración se imprimirán  cantidadPares + 1 números pares
            cantidadPares++;

            // siempre se imprimen tres números impares
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                // si ya se generaron todos lo números terminar
                if(contador == cantidadAGenerar) break;
                // guardar el número generado en el arreglo
                numerosGenerados[contador++] = inicioImpares;
                // incrementar el siguiente número impar
                inicioImpares -=2;
            }

        }

        // imprimir la secuencia generada
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numerosGenerados));

    }
```

Comment: Una duda, porque me tira este error? com/mycompany/java/Java1.java:[4,15] class, interface, or enum expected

Comment: Seguro lo copiaste tal cual, debes copiar el codigo dentro de tu clase.